# Как правильно согласовать предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Разрушение памятников культуры называется вандализмом".
ИЛИ:
"Разрушение памятников культуры называется вандализм".

Answer (score 3):

*Разрушение памятников культуры называется вандализмом.* Или: *Разрушение памятников культуры -- это вандализм.*